# Odd cursor behaviour for cursor in content editable with form elements

Tags: javascript, forms, checkbox, cursor, contenteditable

http://jsfiddle.net/yaPqr/

If you move the cursor from one side of the div to the other one char at a time you'll notice that when you get to the checkbox it doesn't behave as you'd expect (at least I'd expect anyway)

At the extreme left you'd expect right once would move you past the checkbox and before the space and one more would move you to the first char of the sentence, but it takes two right arrow keystrokes to get you to the other side of the checkbox and then you've skipped the space. Is this for some reason I can't descern the expected behaviour?

Comment: Not certain, but could it be something to do with inability to remove the checkbox, since it isn't a character?

Comment: you can remove the checkbox. If the cursor is on the right side of the checkbox and you delete you'll remove the checkbox. My friend took a look at it last night and he's able to make it respond correctly if he wraps it in other elements.

Comment: If you take out the new line characters in the source (so it's all 1 line), you don't have to hit arrow keys 2x, although you have to wait a split second and then the cursor disappears. You can confirm where it is by typing a letter though. Odd behaviour indeed. Is this in all browsers?

Comment: Chrome 19 Mac and Safari as well.